# How to get multiple indexes of parents of child divs with certain classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure if my title explains what I need to do properly but its the closest I could get.

I have been needing to get the indexes of divs with the class ui-selected and apply an additional class to the divs with the class "ui-selected" ...but also to the blocks directly above it so it creates a vertical line (best to see the demo link below to understand what I mean)

https://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/6b2s1hhc/#base

I've managed to do this but to a degree but I am only able to grab the first index of each div with ui-selected.

If you look at the example you can see that in each row there are blocks of 8 and these are contained in the parent div "fader-section".

I have managed to get multiple indexes for each div with "ui-selected" and this works ok in each indivudal "fader-section". If there is another ui-selected that starts in the next "fader-section" then it just doesn't work right.

Basically what I need to do is - anywhere there is the orange highlight "ui-selected" and the layer-lock is clicked I need to highlight every block above and below that.

I've tried using each that got me a little bit closer to what I needed to do and I tried doing the same with the fader-section but it just wasn't working, so I'm quite stuck now.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="layer-lock">I am a lock</a>
<div class="new-layer">
    <div class="sub-layer">
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty ui-selected"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty ui-selected"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty ui-selected"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty ui-selected"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty ui-selected"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty ui-selected"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty ui-selected"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty ui-selected"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<!--new layer-->
<div class="new-layer">
    <div class="sub-layer">
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<!--new layer-->
<div class="new-layer">
    <div class="sub-layer">
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="fader-section">
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
            <div class="fader-empty"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.layer-lock {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:60px;
    background:green;
    z-index:99;
}
.new-layer {
    clear:both;
    white-space:nowrap;
    float:left;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;
    font-size:0;
}
.sub-layer {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.fader-section {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.fader-empty {
    background-color:#e5e7ea;
    border-left:1px solid #a1a1a1;
    border-top:1px solid #a1a1a1;
    border-bottom:1px solid #a1a1a1;
    height:240px;
    width:44px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:12px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.shoo {
    background-color:green !important;
}
.ui-selected {
    background:orange;
}
.layer-locked {
    background:red;

}
.moo23 {
    background:green;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('.layer-lock').click(function() {

    $(".fader-empty.ui-selected").each(function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        console.log("suz" + newindex);
        var newindex = $('.fader-empty.ui-selected').index();       
        var findex =$('.fader-empty.ui-selected').parent('.fader-section').index();


        var moo =  $('.fader-section:nth-child(' + (findex + 1) + ')').find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (newindex + index +1) + ')');

        $(moo).toggleClass('moo23');
    });
});


$('.fader-empty').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-selected');   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number of fader-section in each layer is same i.e. if your HTML structure is uniform then you can use that fact to toggle selected columns.

JS:

```
$('.layer-lock').click(function () {
    var oneRowElems = $('.sub-layer:eq(0) .fader-section:eq(0) .fader-empty').length * $('.sub-layer:eq(0) .fader-section').length;
    var totalRows = $('.sub-layer').length;
    var totalElems = oneRowElems * totalRows;

    var selectedColumns = {};

    $(".fader-empty").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('ui-selected')) {
            selectedColumns[index % oneRowElems] = 1;
        }
    });

    for (var i in selectedColumns) {
        // Toggle Columns Above
        for (var j = parseInt(i) - oneRowElems; j > 0; j -= oneRowElems) {
            $('.fader-empty').eq(j).toggleClass('moo23');
        }

        // Toggle Columns Below
        for (var j = parseInt(i); j < totalElems; j += oneRowElems) {
            $('.fader-empty').eq(j).toggleClass('moo23');
        }
    }
});

$('.fader-empty').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-selected');
});
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5k6t31zp/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/5k6t31zp/3/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that's what you want, but I think you're looking for [`:eq(X)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) pseudo selector.
Also, inside loop you should refer to `this` (item in current iteration).
Using the `.fader-empty.ui-selected`, it will always return `index` of the very first item with `.ui-selected` class.

**CODE UPDATED**
(Added `$('.fader-empty.moo23').length` indicator)

```
$('.layer-lock').click(function() {
    var l = $('.fader-empty.moo23').length;
    $(".fader-empty.ui-selected").each(function() {
        var newindex = $(this).index();
        var findex   = $(this).parent().index();
        var item     = $('.new-layer').find('.fader-section:eq('+findex+') .fader-empty:eq('+newindex+')');
        l && item.removeClass('moo23') || item.addClass('moo23');
    });
});
```

<s>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bddywbnx/)</s> [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bue25x25/)

---

There's an example with fixed `$('.fader-empty').click()` method:
[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4sascbnj/)

Comment: Much simpler solution than mine.. :) ( Not sure if OP wants it, but just wanted to mention that this will not work if there are two orange highlights in one column. https://jsfiddle.net/4sascbnj/2/ )

Comment: @Chitrang  that is a very good point. This code I can get my head around much easier but it doesn't work with both highlighted and it will need to. Thanks for spotting that

Comment: I'll take a look at this later today.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you are over-complicating your JS.

I think this will achieve what you want:

```
$('.layer-lock').click(function() {
    $(".fader-empty.ui-selected").each(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("moo34");
    });
});


$('.fader-empty').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ui-selected');   
});
```

The toggle class will remove the class though if it is already there. If you are looking to keep those with the moo34 class everytime you click lock button, you will have to adjust this slightly to check for the moo34 class before add/togling it. If this is the case, you may want to try:

```
 $('.layer-lock').click(function() {
        $(".fader-empty.ui-selected").each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass("moo34")){
                 $(this).addClass("moo34");
             }
          });
    });


    $('.fader-empty').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('ui-selected');   
    });
```

Comment: it kind of is a little bit more complicated as when the ui-selected class is there it needs to add the layer-locked to all of the blocks above and below. like in a strip. this has been acheived so far but what I'm struggling with is that when multiple ui-selected classes are there, if it spill over into the next fader section then it doesn't highlight those ones

Comment: By click a block, do you mean a div.fader-empty?

Comment: yes sorry, if I've referred to anything as "block" I should say .fader-empty

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/mw8zm9y5/#base

This was the starting point and this was how it originally worked but now I'm trying to make it so that when multiple "fader-empty" are selected that is adds the highlight strip down across all

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not 100% on what you are looking for, let go from here... what is or istn happening : https://jsfiddle.net/mw8zm9y5/2/

Comment: I think the starting point probably needs to be the link I put in the comment.  as that is working perfectly it's just the multiselection that is not working great

Comment: when the div turns orange and you click on the layer-lock it should turn all of the divs in a vertical strip directly above and below.

so this works in this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/mw8zm9y5/#base

Comment: however the next think I was trying to do was to do this for multiple selections like here. But you will see that if you make multiple selections it will only highlight the first strip in red and not the others.

https://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/c2g345nm/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question right but the code below selects all the orange boxes and changes their color to green:

```
$('.layer-lock').click(function() {
    $(".fader-empty.ui-selected")
        .parent(".fader-section")       
        .children(".ui-selected")
        .each(function(index, element) {            
            $(element).toggleClass('moo23');
        });
});
```